# How to pass MVC values from TableView to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I am new to Swift and I've been working on a simple app that will allow me to present information from a MVC in to a `TableView`. What I would like to do is - when a row's selected in the `TableView` it will then present the remainder of the information in a new `ViewController`. I've managed to call the "name" variable from the MVC to the original tableView using the init method, however I am struggling to track the `tableViewCells` and place the remaining data in the `viewController`.

Heres the code:

```
// Model Variables 

import Foundation

class Close: NSObject {

var name: String
var technique: String
var example: String
var howItWorks: String

init(name: String, technique: String, example: String, howItWorks: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.technique = technique
    self.example = example
    self.howItWorks = howItWorks
} 
}

import Foundation

class CloseGroup: NSObject {

var name: String
var closesArray: [Close]

init(name: String, closesArray: [Close]) {
    self.name = name
    self.closesArray = closesArray
} 
}
```

Here is where I keep the data I would like to present in the TableView as well as the ViewController

```
class CloseDataManager: NSObject {

static func createCloseGroup() -> [CloseGroup] {

    let basicCloses = CloseGroup(name: "Basic Closes",
                                 closesArray: [
                                    Close(name: "Ask the manager",
                                          technique: "One thing we can all agree on is that people love to spend money right? Nevertheless we all have a limit, some people have no problem spending a lot while other people may not want to spend that much. This doesnt take away from the fact that regardless whatever your spending you want the best for your money, now once you've been able to create value and the prospect is interest however after looking at the price they say 'As nice as it is, I simply cant afford it' - this technique comes in to play.",
                                          example: "Look I can understand that this is a bit more then you expected to pay, let me ask you how much can/are you afford/willing to pay per month? 300…Ok Perfect, we have a package for that… ",
                                          howItWorks: "This close works by carefully tailoring finance of a product/service to fit the other persons ability or willingness to pay. ‘I cant afford this’most of the time is not an objection, its an excuse. If they really don’t want to purchase the product they will rapidly jump to other objections. Be careful when speaking to clients about finance as this subject to many people is very touchy, be aware of the words that you use because once you cross the line of finance the clients guard will go back up and you will need to put in some work to bring the barrier back down."),

                                    Close(name: "Compliment Close",
                                          technique: "One thing we can all agree on is that people love to spend money right? Nevertheless we all have a limit, some people have no problem spending a lot while other people may not want to spend that much. This doesnt take away from the fact that regardless whatever your spending you want the best for your money, now once you've been able to create value and the prospect is interest however after looking at the price they say 'As nice as it is, I simply cant afford it' - this technique comes in to play.",
                                          example: "Look I can understand that this is a bit more then you expected to pay, let me ask you how much can/are you afford/willing to pay per month? 300…Ok Perfect, we have a package for that… ",
                                          howItWorks: "This close works by carefully tailoring finance of a product/service to fit the other persons ability or willingness to pay. ‘I cant afford this’most of the time is not an objection, its an excuse. If they really don’t want to purchase the product they will rapidly jump to other objections. Be careful when speaking to clients about finance as this subject to many people is very touchy, be aware of the words that you use because once you cross the line of finance the clients guard will go back up and you will need to put in some work to bring the barrier back down.") )]
```

//Here is my TableView Code:

```
import UIKit

class BasicClosesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var basicCloses: CloseGroup

init(basicCloses: CloseGroup) {
    self.basicCloses = basicCloses
    super.init(style: .plain)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BasicClosesCell")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return basicCloses.closesArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicClosesCell", for: indexPath)
    let close: Close = basicCloses.closesArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = close.name
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let close: Close = basicCloses.closesArray[indexPath.row]
    print(close.example)
}
 }
```

//This is where I would like to present the remaining variables from my MVC:

```
import UIKit

class ExplanationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var allCloses: CloseGroup

init(allCloses: CloseGroup) {
    self.allCloses = allCloses
    super.init(style: .plain)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
} 
}
```

Comment: can you please try this required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Melvin Asare may be the issue is just due to your below snippet

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Can you please replace it with

```
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { 
super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
}
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I tried it but once I added the code it said that self.allCloses has not been initialised at super.init call?

Comment: replace your var allCloses: CloseGroup with var allCloses: CloseGroup? and try

Comment: lol thank you! swift can be very annoying sometimes but thank you very much.